# KiCAD: Cannot see traces on a PCB side which has been filled with copper

Tags: layout, kicad

I made a bottom side copper fill.

Then I drew traces on the back side, coming from the top side copper. (Top side copper trace -> via -> Draw Trace -> via -> Back to top side trace drawing.)

When I hit `v` in order to see the bottom side traces, I see no traces, just a huge green zone.

[image]

However, the amount of unrouted traces goes down.

Why does this happen?
How can I see the bottom side traces?

I thought I should be able to see something like this:

[image]

This is coming from the 'Getting to Blinky 5.0' KiCAD tutorial series.

NOTE: I am using JLCPCB design rules, coming from this template:

https://github.com/sethhillbrand/kicad_templates

EDIT: This is my layers manager:
[image]

Comment: Do you have the solder mask layer visible?

Comment: @RonBeyer Hi! I am new to KiCAD, so i am not sure what you mean. But i updated my question with a picture of my Layers Manager.

Comment: right click, or somewhere else and look for repour. it has to redraw the layer so to speak.

Comment: @EdwinFairchild Thank you! I pressed 'B' because i know this does the redrawing and it worked! If you want, make a proper answer, so i can upvote and mark it as the selected answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try pressing B. That will re-draw all fill zones on the board.

Answer (score 2):

Pressing `b` will Fill or refill the zones. Usually, I copper fill the board after the routing is done. Or you can turn off filled zone by clicking the `Do not show filled area in zones` button on the verticle toolbar on left.

You can also have the same effect when you run the DRC check, refilling one of the steps in the check.